# Deserialize metaplex token metadata instruction data

Tags: metaplex, deserialization, decode, instruction

I would like to dezerialise instruction data to the metaplex token metadata program in node js.
For example the instruction data of creating a metadata account v2 or when creating a master edition v3. As in this example: https://solscan.io/tx/62p3dbFieGBFLXFvzcwPMFHhx1eTs5hjVDPRHFFsL8L1HsNxg6C5mN3xhmBUtKbFd8QQvRwnwX6XKrmjKEqZcNQd (1.2 and 1.6).

The getParsedTransaction from @solana/web3.js SDK does not parse metaplex token program instruction data.

The reason that I want to deserialize instruction data instead of a metaplex account, is to reduce RPC calls.

Comment: Have you tried using the metaplex JS SDK for achieving this ?

Comment: In metaplex JS SDK I can't find anything usefull, however [this](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/js/src/generated/instructions/CreateMetadataAccountV3.ts) link seems helpful (metaplex program library). I see CreateMetadataAccountV3Struct.serialize, but I do not know if this would work with .deserialize also. Because for example creators parameter has variable length, so how would program know where it ends?

Comment: There aren't any deserializers for instructions available unfortunately. With that said, it should be possible to decode an instruction given the IDL, so perhaps the anchor team can add that capability for you!

Comment: @JonC yes I had the same idea, but the token metadata program does not have an IDL (yet), right?

Comment: I found this https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/js/idl/mpl_token_metadata.json -- it should be what you need!

Comment: it does have an IDL and the low level SDKs are generated using it